# Private Variables and Class-local References

Tags: python, class, reference, local, private

I am learning Python from [here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables-and-class-local-references).

In Section 9.6 (Private Variables and Class-local References), the last paragraph states that:

> Notice that code passed to exec, eval() or execfile() does not
>   consider the classname of the invoking class to be the current class;
>   this is similar to the effect of the global statement, the effect of
>   which is likewise restricted to code that is byte-compiled together.
>   The same restriction applies to getattr(), setattr() and delattr(), as
>   well as when referencing **dict** directly.

I do not understand what they mean. Please provide an explanation or give me some examples to demonstrate this concept.

Comment: Good question. I too understood 0% of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Imagine you have a class with a local reference:

```
class Foo:
    __attr= 5
```

Inside the class, this attribute can be referenced as `__attr`:

```
class Foo:
    __attr= 5
    print(__attr) # prints 5
```

But not outside of the class:

```
print(Foo.__attr) # raises AttributeError
```

But it's different if you use `eval`, `exec`, or `execfile` inside the class:

```
class Foo:
    __attr= 5
    
    print(__attr) # prints 5
    exec 'print(__attr)' # raises NameError
```

This is explained by the paragraph you quoted. `exec` does not consider `Foo` to be the "current class", so the attribute cannot be referenced (unless you reference it as `Foo._Foo__attr`).

Comment: follow your answer, I deduct that, the namespace of exec(), or eval() don't include private attributes? And i still have not idea about: "this is similar to the effect of the global statement, the effect of which is likewise restricted to code that is byte-compiled together. The same restriction applies to getattr(), setattr() and delattr(), as well as when referencing dict directly."

Comment: @user3044330 The `global` statement only affects the code in the current code block (_"code that is byte-compiled together"_). It's the same thing for the name-mangling of private attributes. The code in the `exec` or `eval` isn't byte-compiled together with the class code, so no name-mangling occurs there.

Comment: It's mean exec() or eval() are "global statement" and couldn't use in "class block"? You've helped a lot and I will search for exec(), eval() for deep knowledge about them. Thank you so much.

Comment: @user3044330 No, it doesn't mean that. You can use `eval` and `exec` anywhere. It just means that both the name mangling and the `global` statement only affect code in the same code block.

Answer (score 0):

class Foo:
Foo._Foo__attr= 5

```
print(Foo._Foo__attr) # prints 5
exec 'print(Foo._Foo__attr)' # CORRECTED REFERENCE, PRINTS OUTPUT 5  
                             # exec does not consider Foo to be 
                             #the "current class", 
                             # so the private attribute cannot be referenced 
                            #(unless you reference it as Foo._Foo__attr).
```